# Less CSS editor with autocomplete?

Tags: css, less

Is there any software for `LESS CSS` editor.

`Note`: I want software with auto complete feature.

Please help with your suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at crunch, doesn't have autocomplete yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/) for all my web-related coding needs, and it supports LESS auto-complete just fine.

Comment: Wow! Awesome support. I'm very happy with PHPStorm. Thank you , Thank you very much OneOfOne.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual Studio, this extension has a nice support for LESS:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f

Comment: unless you want to use nested media queries or reliable syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

They have a number of useful packages to install, one of them being All Autocomplete. I think it would fit what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Espresso](https://espressoapp.com) has a LESS [Sugar](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611030841/https://github.com/mkoistinen/LESS.sugar) (gosh I always wanted to say that in a silly accent :-)

and it has autocomplete support.

Installation is simple:

> - cd ~/Library/Application Support/Espresso/Sugars
> - git clone https://github.com/mkoistinen/LESS.sugar.git LESS.sugar